# Integrating an IMU with rtabmap

Tags: slam, imu, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My rtabmap is having a very hard time with keeping track of orientation during both localization and mapping. I'm wondering if there is any easy way to feed in IMU data so that the direction of gravity can help orient the images and produce better results. That is, I'm wondering if I can associate orientation data with every frame such that it improves rtabmap's SLAM capabilities.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248109/integrating-an-imu-with-rtabmap/) by [natejgardner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22499/natejgardner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related topics:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/221103/combine-imu-with-visual-odometry-using-rtabmap/
  http://answers.ros.org/question/242417/sensor-fusion-of-imu-and-asus-for-rtab-map-with-robot_localization/
  http://answers.ros.org/question/239646/build-a-map-with-husky-laser-and-kinectrealsense/

As mentioned in one of these posts,  [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package could be used to do a loosely sensor fusion of IMU and visual odometry. The launch file [sensor_fusion.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/tests/sensor_fusion.launch) is a simple example combining Kinect+IMU with rtabmap.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Danilo_BR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32625/danilo_br/) on 2017-11-14**:
HI! I was just checking this sensor_fusion.launch and is it correct to assume that it is just combining position information from odom0 and orientation information from imu0 (if argument imu_ignore_acc is set)? wouldnt be better to set true the orientation parameters of odom0_config? rookie question

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-11-14**:
1-Yes. 2-It depends: covariance should be carefully tuned if you want to fuse orientations of both sensors. The example is like assuming that IMU orientation covariance is a lot smaller than vo.